# Add a border to hovered button CSS

Tags: css, button, hover, border

Hey I wanna add a border to my button when this is hovered. Below my code:

```
    button{
    background-color: #e876f5;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  button:focus{
    outline: none;
  }

  button:hover{
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #e876f5;
    color:  #e876f5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

I thought that adding `border: 2px solid #e876f5;` would suffice but when I hover the button there is no border. What should I do?

Comment: I don't see a problem here, can you show us the html?

Comment: As @Zdravko say all work, the only thing that comes to mind is that there is an override on the class.

Comment: There was border none in my HTML... `<button type="button" style="width: 600px; height:40px; border:none;">`it works now

Answer (score 0):

Button first add the border and after us hover border like this.

```
   button{
    background-color: #e876f5;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border:2px solid #e876f5;/* add normal button css */
  }
```

```css
  button{
    background-color: #e876f5;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border:2px solid #e876f5;
  }

  button:focus{
    outline: none;
  }

  button:hover{
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #e876f5;
    color:  #e876f5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```